# What's the name of this operator "+=" ?

Tags: programming-languages, operators

What's the name of this operator "+=" ?

Comment: I just call it "plus equals".

Comment: Me too. It's straightforward.

Comment: "not a real question"? Let's see, it starts with one of the "question" words (who, what, where, how, why, when, ...) and ends with a question mark. It's even related to programming. I think I'll vote to reopen this one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It, along with `-=`, `*=`, etc., are called the [augmented assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment) operators in Python, and "compound assignment" operators everywhere else.

Comment: Twaddle, the word augment, in all its variations, is mentioned exactly three times in the latest C++ draft standard and not at all in reference to +=. They're simply operators, that's all, it doesn't have a special name. You should base your information on something a little better than an orphaned Wikipedia entry :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Comment: I stand corrected: coming from a C background, the ISO standards are the bible for me but I didn't notice that "programming" was the only tag. Apologies and +1 by way of saying sorry.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Well, to be fair, everyone else *does* call them "compound assignment" operators. But doesn't "augmented assignment" sound just so much more *awesome*? Anyways, fixed.

Comment: I've actually never heard them called *any* of those. One wag (no names, no pack drill, and they've since deleted the answer) gave us "increment compound assignment operator" which I thought was hilarious - surely plus-equals is so much more succinct :-)

Comment: Here's an example of the use of *augmented* for "+=" and "++" in C: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/689766f8ffcbee5c.

Answer (score 14):

The name is "plus equal" operator!

Comment: +1 this isn't the name, but if you say it 99% of programmers will know what you're talking about. Language is about communication, not about perfection.

Comment: +1 - that's what I've caled it and I don't think I can remember working with anyone who habitually called it anything else.

Answer (score 13):

In c# it's called the [addition assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

That is the **[Addition Assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)** operator.

Answer (score 1):

+= is the plus and Equal operator.
If you assign a+=3
  That means u assign the expression are a=a+3.