# PHP: How to access array values returned by a static function?

Tags: php, static, oop

I am running following code, `getAccount()` is a static function,

```
$ac_info = AccountClass::getAccount($ac_code);
print_r($ac_info);
```

and getting following output

```
AccountClass Object ( [account_code] => email@gmail.com [username] => XYZ [email] => [first_name] => [last_name] => [company_name] => [id] => email@gmail.com [balance_in_cents] => 0 [created_at] => 1271333048 [state] => active )
```

But I want to access the value of "account_code" shown above, how to access it, and `AccountClass Object` what is this, this is array or what? I am not getting it properly.

Please explain what is `AccountClass Object` and how to access value of properties account_code, first_name inside this array.

Thanks

Comment: [Knock yourself out](http://php.net/oop5)

Comment: Why it is marked -1, is it already on SO? I used search, but didn't found anything.

Comment: Prashant, if find it amazing that you have 1000+ points on SO and ask such beginner questions. Makes one wonder has SO rating system gone FUBAR.

Comment: Ya that's OK, but I am not an exp. programmer in PHP (OOPS), that's why asked this question. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Probably because it's the first hit on Google when searching for `php object`. But it might be easier to find the `$variable->key` part when you already know what to look for though. In any case it's good advice to read through the PHP manual first when you're really diving into OOP.

Comment: Basic questions such as this are not appropriate for Stack Overflow, and usually indicate that the asker has not spent sufficient (or indeed, any) time reading through documentation and/or tutorials.

Comment: I've seen [worse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800561/position-of-image-not-changing-with-window-scroll/2800592#2800592) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107333/whats-the-name-of-this-operator/2107355#2107355) that could have easily been looked up. @ignacio got 17 up-votes for answering one.

Comment: @bschaeffer: To be fair, I *did* have to really dig to find the second part of that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ac_info` is an object of `AccountClass` class.
`account_code`, `username`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name` and all the rest are object properties.

You can access them in a way:

```
echo $ac_info->account_code;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$ac_info->account_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also :

```
print_r(get_class_methods($ac_info));
```

You will see an array of the methods in the AccountClass class. Because if $account_code is private, you won't be able to read it directly, but you will have to use the getter, something like :

`$ac_info->getAccountCode();`